# Python and asyncio with Inotify weird issue

Tags: python, python-asyncio, inotify

I'm having a weird issue when using Python asyncio with Inotify libraries. I have tried both asyncinotify and minotaur third party libraries and both give me the same issue. I have created a simple example that demonstrates the issue:

```py
import asyncio
from asyncinotify import Inotify, Mask
from contextlib import suppress


async def watcher_task():
    watchdir = "/home/user/test/"
    
    with Inotify() as n:
        n.add_watch(watchdir, Mask.CLOSE_WRITE)
        async for event in n:
            print(event)
            
                       
async def main():
    task = asyncio.create_task(watcher_task())
    print('running task for 20 seconds')
    await asyncio.sleep(20)
    
    # Creating files in the watchdir will now show/print
    # the event happening in watcher_task(). No issues
    
    print('cancelling task')
    task.cancel()
    with suppress(asyncio.CancelledError):
        await task
        
    print('creating task again')
    task = asyncio.create_task(watcher_task())
    print('running task for 20 seconds')
    
    # After cancelling the task, and recreating it,
    # no events are triggered/printed now in watcher_task
    # when files are created in the watchdir... WHY!?
    
    await asyncio.sleep(20)
       
       
asyncio.run(main())
```

Is there something obvious I'm missing? Why does Inotify only work the first time the task is created, and not subsequent times?

Comment: Quoting an answer post by scaramanga, which I suspect might be deleted for not being an answer, in order to keep what seems a valuable comment: "I am author of minotaur, I can reproduce this error and it is a bug. A fix should be on the way in the next version."

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug with the library itself: https://gitlab.com/Taywee/asyncinotify/-/issues/6

Answer (score 1):

I am author of minotaur, I can reproduce this error and it is a bug. A fix is in v0.1.0